# Find number of d's that satisfies $d, d+1, d+2... = N$ for an $N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have a challenge about a cat in a trip where he can walk in the way of $d, d+1, d+2...$ and the sum of that should give $N$, given an $N$, how many ways of chosing $d$ are posible?

Example:

$N=30$ -> $Ans=3$

$d_1=4; d_2=6; d_3=8$

For $d_1: 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 30$

Edit:

Another way to see it is: How many subsets in the sumation up to N are posible in the way $(\sum (d+n) - \sum(d-1))$=N

Comment: How many terms do you add up?

Comment: It can be as many as posible as long as the result give N

Comment: Do you mean $d_3=9$, because $9+10+11=30$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DaniTorres if you are asking for the amount of possibilities that depends directly on whether there is a restriction on the amount of terms

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch there's no restriction in the amount of terms, I've updated the description

Comment: Related; my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133472/find-the-number-of-ways-to-express-1050-as-sum-of-consecutive-integers/3133617#3133617). The number of ways to write an integer $N$ as a sum of consecutive integers is precisely twice the number of odd divisors of $N$. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139842/in-how-many-ways-can-a-number-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-consecutive-numbers) and the many other questions that link to it.

Comment: What about $d_4=30$? Or $d_0=-3$ because
$$(-3)+(-2)+(-1)+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=30.$$

Comment: @Servaes The terms shouln't start from negative numbers, only positive ones, but your link to the other answer has the way to solve it, thanks!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59131/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking the number of solutions of:

$$\sum_{i=x}^{y} i=N$$
$$\frac{y^2+y-x^2-x}{2}=N$$
$$(y-x)(y+x)+(y-x)=2N$$
$$(y-x)(y+x+1)=2N$$

Since $y+x+1>y-x$ , $y+x+1$ must be a divisor bigger than $\sqrt{2N}$, and the other one a divisor smaller than $\sqrt{2N}$.

$$y-x=d_1 \ \ \ y+x+1=d_2$$

Summing:

$$2y+1=d_1+d_2$$
$$y=\frac{d_1+d_2-1}{2}\Rightarrow x=\frac{-d_1+d_2-1}{2}$$

At least one(and only one can be) among $d_1$ and $d_2$ is even, so the number of solutions is equal to the number of odd divisors of $2N$ that are smaller than its root plus the number of divisors that contains all of the factors $2$ in $2N$(or  bigger it's symmetric). In general if you have:

$$N=2^{\alpha}\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{a_i}$$
$$2N=2^{\alpha+1}\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{a_i}$$

Since there is always an odd divisor the answer is  simply:

$$\sigma_0(\prod_\limits{i=1}^{k} p_i^{a_i})=\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1+a_i)$$

:/

Comment: lol I thought my solution was just partial

Comment: This is precisely the answer given in a bunch of linked duplicate questions.

Comment: @Servaes it doesn't matter I had fun